# What is the best way to learn logical fallacies?

Tags: logic, fallacies

I want to learn logic better, I know a few fallacies but I've read no books mostly just stuff on the Internet. I see them everywhere, but sometimes I don't know what the fallacy is called. I am a pretty decent logician, but I want to learn the terminology well. Where do I start? What books do you recommend?

Comment: If you "want to learn logic better" you might want to learn valid inferences, before/instead identifying wrong ones! Or are you interested in reasoning and critical thinking? Then you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies. This [discussion on Meta](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/325/1582) might help you clarify whether you are interested in formal logic or critical thinking.

Comment: Interesting question, but not appropriate for this site for the reasons indicated below. We prefer to direct these types of questions to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), as they have no (easily discernible) real answer.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this website: [yourlogicalfallacyis.com](http://yourlogicalfallacyis.com). They also have a funny poster that you can print or buy.

Comment: Nice but if I wanted a site like that I'd just use the "Taxonomy of Logical Fallacies" on The Fallacy Files site, which I have been using... as a time consuming parrot. I'm not learning enough from it. I need a book or something.