# How to self-learn legal arguments, logic, and reasoning?

Tags: logic, reference-request, fallacies, philosophy-of-law

What are some readable, eloquent  (without legalese)  books on arguments, fallacies, logic, and reasoning, as applied and used in law? This question is aimed towards a greenhorn/tenderfoot with minimal knowledge in law and philosophy, but who's interested in the law.

I'm interested only in 'applied' or or practical pragmatic philosophy, and not overly formal or abstract or pure books on these subjects.

I've been reading [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674062485) and [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0813344646), and a random search on Amazon induced [1. this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0960851445)  and [2. this](http://www.amazon.com/The-Tools-Argument-Lawyers-Think/dp1481246380/ref=pd_cp_b_3), but are these helpful, relevant, and lucid?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a good fit for the site, like [others](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-logical-fallacies) asked in a similar manner. We are hear to provide answers to philosophical inquiries; the science of learning is more psychology and outside our scope. We can offer some books here and there but again that'd just be someone's opinion rather than the single, definitive answer we prefer for the questions asked here. At best this can be a Community Wiki question with a growing but helpful list of tips and strategies...

Comment: I sometimes like listening to Supreme Court arguments (which you can find online): the better ones contain high-quality "legal arguments, logic, and reasoning".

Comment: I guess that the practice of law is often less about logic and more about evidence.
I quite like [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions) -- answers try to supply good evidence on each subject. Sometimes (as in law) the evidence seems contradictory (some studies seem to show one thing, other studies seem to show another) and an answer must try to discern a truth.
On the Skeptics forum, answers that based on pure logic ("Reason tells us that so-and-so must be true, given that etc.") are not allowed: it's finding the best *evidence* and weighing the evidence that matters.

Answer (score -2):

Although I have limited experience, I have come to the conclusion that if you **learn logic**, and are good at it, you will be able to apply it to law with no difficulty, that's because logic is used to write the (most?) laws.